# Where is  /var/log/messages?

Tags: 11.04, log

Just installed natty, and cannot find `/var/log/messages`. Also, `/var/log/daemon.log` is missing. What happened? Why are they no longer present? And where I can find the same log information?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`/var/log/messages` has been deleted from Natty.
 You can find the same info in `/var/log/syslog`. Note that everything logged to `messages` was also logged to `syslog`.

Comment: For reference: by default, the rules specifying what gets logged where are in `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`, as they're loaded by the `$IncludeConfig` directive in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

Comment: issue referencing this discussion: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/794727

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to check the real time progress of system.
`tail -f /var/log/syslog`
Using CTRL-C to exit out from that.

For example, you can open up the terminal and plug in a USB on your computer, the OS will log what type of USB, where is it mounting to, if the tracker-store.service is successful.