# I can't shut down nor reboot without console

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, reboot

After update from 11.04 to 11.10 an wired conduct appears in my machine:

Shutdown GUI methods (including reboot) cause only a log off, and in the login screen, shutdown nor reboot options do anything (if you wonder, reboot appears in the shutdown dialog).

The only way i can reboot or shutdown is trough console `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo reboot`. This is OK for me, but not for the rest of the users.

How to fix this?

**Update**

The syslog output when select *shutdown* from my desktop is:

```
AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
CRON[5095]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
CRON[5094]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
kernel: [17027.614974] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
kernel: [17027.616510] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
kernel: [17027.618037] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
kernel: [17027.619557] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
kernel: [17027.621046] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
kernel: [17027.621051] psmouse.c: issuing reconnect request
acpid: client 1032[0:0] has disconnected
acpid: client connected from 1032[0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
gnome-session[1836]: WARNING: Unable to stop system: Authorization is required
acpid: client 1032[0:0] has disconnected
acpid: client connected from 6055[0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6134 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' high priority at nice level -11.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6139 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' RT at priority 5.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6140 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' RT at priority 5.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
```

I suspect that the line `gnome-session[1836]: WARNING: Unable to stop system: Authorization is required` is related to the issue.

When selecting `shutdown` from the login screen, the output is the same from the line pointed. This is the output:

```
gnome-session[1836]: WARNING: Unable to stop system: Authorization is required
acpid: client 1032[0:0] has disconnected
acpid: client connected from 6055[0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6134 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' high priority at nice level -11.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6139 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' RT at priority 5.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Successfully made thread 6140 of process 6134 (n/a) owned by '119' RT at priority 5.
rtkit-daemon[1313]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
acpid: client 6055[0:0] has disconnected
acpid: client connected from 6055[0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

Comment: First, please remove your rant about Reboot in Shutdown dialog. This is unrelated to your question. You can file a bug if it bothers you. Second, please take a look at the logfiles (e.g. /var/log/messages) after a failed attempt to shutdown via GUI.

Comment: @Jan i did what you suggested me. Also note that /var/log/messages no longer exists; i didn't know that, but [1] showed me what to do: use /var/log/syslog

[1] http://askubuntu.com/q/51265/10580

Comment: I believe you found the offending line in the log files. Hope someone can help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have rabbitmq installed? That is the culprit for me. Here is bug ticket for it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitmq-server/+bug/670289

Comment: Just to say, adding the official RabbitMQ repo and installing as per http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html installs the latest version and fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, but for me it is solved with the following solution. Maybe it will help your system too. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792/comments/24

See also the rest of the bugreport at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (also a similiar one when I was using Gentoo) and this worked for me: https://www.grendelman.net/wp/policykit-adventures/. Tested it on 12.04 and the problem is gone. I'd use it as a temporary fix though, 'cause something's telling me it's not really that safe when everyone's allowed to reboot the host without any checks for other running sessions. In my case this bug was only manifesting itself when I had other sessions running on VTs, or when there was someone else logged in via SSH. Anyway, hope this fixes it for you. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

I just experienced the same problem on my Linux Mint 12 (aka Ubuntu-11.10) with Cinnamon desktop. The "restart" GUI button logged me out instead of restarting.

### Findings

I found your post but met a different solution that "worked for me". I had the same message in my syslog:

```
gnome-session[12937]: WARNING: Unable to restart system: Authorization is required
```

I found out that I had **two users logged in** on my machine:

```
$ who
root     tty1         2012-12-28 10:14
evigier  pts/0        2012-12-28 10:14 (:0)
```

**root** was logged on my main tty, aka `ctrl + alt + F1`. I started it yesterday because I needed to do some evil admin tasks I cannot remember of.

### Solution

I logged out my root user from `tty1`, got back to my desktop `ctrl + alt + F7`, then pressed `restart`.