# Ubuntu 12.10 shutdown/restart from login-screen

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t shut down nor reboot without console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71506/i-cant-shut-down-nor-reboot-without-console)

When I click shutdown or restart from login-screen, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you logged into any of the virtual terminals at tty1,tty2, etc..?

Comment: I was not logged into any virtual terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue for some users in 12.04 and 12.10 where shutdown/restart only logs them out of their user session and does not shut down the machine, and using shutdown/restart from the login screen does nothing. It is apparently [just a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/987220). You can try some of the solutions you may be able to find in Google but nothing has worked reliably for me.

You can still shutdown your computer by opening a tty terminal (CTRL-ALT-F2 through F6), logging in as root, and entering

```
shutdown -h now
```

which will shutdown the system or

```
reboot
```

which will reboot it.

Comment: Thanks! This helps, but there is still bug in Ubuntu. Do you have this problem too?