# Unable to shut down Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I am unable to shutdown via shutdown option. If I issue a shutdown the system goes back to the login prompt. 
I can shutdown the system only via terminal using `sudo shutdown -h now`.
Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: First use `sudo shutdown -P now` instead of `-h`. Next try `sudo shutdown -P now` and again turn the computer ON. Now, try shutting it down using the GUI.

Comment: no it wont works out @green7

Comment: @green7- itried with that command. but it doesn't works out

Comment: I'm looking into it. Will get back with some solution. :)

Comment: Do you have `rabbitmq` installed? Also please attach your `~/.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: Also paste the output of `who` command.

Comment: yes Rabbitmq has installed in my computer

Comment: who
thomson pts/0        2013-04-16 16:45 (:0)

Comment: Most probably `rabbitmq` is the culprit. Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/74295/83046) answer.

Comment: http://pastie.org/7598945 from here, you can take a look at my ~/.xsession-errors

Comment: Did you look at the answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/74295/83046

Comment: @green7 Thank you very much. i had resolved the problem with your help. This problem because of rabbitmq sever. i just removed it and now my system is doing fine

Comment: Glad it helped. Would add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be due to `rabbitmq` being installed on your machine.

See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitmq-server/+bug/670289

Remove `rabbitmq` using:

```
sudo apt-get purge rabbitmq-server
```