# Can't shutdown from desktop in 15.10

Tags: shutdown, 15.10

I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 to about 15 days ago. Now i started facing a problem which appeared about 3-5 days ago. I am not able to shutdown my laptop from the desktop, when I click on shutdown from top-right gear icon on desktop, I just logged out but I am able to shutdown from there and also from terminal.
I also checked: [I can't shut down nor reboot without console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71506/i-cant-shut-down-nor-reboot-without-console) but it did not help.

[image]

Hope it helps. Thank You
P.S.-Sometimes my laptop shutdown from left-hand gear icon(as it happened today sometimes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so far It seems this a bug but using command in terminal

> > sudo shutdown now

will shutdown the system.